# Could someone be targeted by analysing their DNA and finding certain weaknesses?

Tags: biology, diseases, viruses

A person was offering me food for few months 3-4 months. I don’t trust this person 100% due to the person having some issues with my family previously. Anyway I kept getting ill almost once to twice per month and once I got very ill it felt like a really strong flu. I caught that person once picking up few pieces of my hair he didn’t realise that I have seen him pick that hair from under my pillow. What can that person use that hair for? Could he send it to someone he knows in a lab in order to analyse and see if a certain thing he is putting in the food is actually working? Or could he have that hair analysed to get health weaknesses (using DNA)? I stopped taking any food offered but I am forced to sometimes take bottles of water from him as I have no choice much due to my financial situation not being great. I can’t be writing personal stuff here but yes I am very likely a target for him as he is afraid of me taking everything he has built because him and his family fell out with my family years back over multi million business. Today I got ill again with slight fever. I have mentioned to him that I want to do a blood test etc especially when I was seriously ill few months back and he said no need for blood test just keep taking paracetamol to reduce your fever. What would you guys do if you were in my situation? Before this situation I was living oceans apart and had no such health issues (I would get ill with fever once in 1-2 years at max) unlike the past few months.

Comment: Welcome Mars to Earth. This is a site for artists, writers and other creators to build fictional-worlds. Besides being off-topic because it's not about that, it also is about personal medical issues. You should seek advice from a professional near yourself, not from random strangers on the net. - Also worth noting that the technology to do what you ask is out of reach of all but major corporations and state actors, at least at present.

Comment: Ok good to hear only state actors have this kind of reach and normal person cant.

Comment: Kept getting ill? Very strong flu? ongoing health complications? [i wonder if anything has happened recently that might explain any of that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_COVID).

Comment: Funnily enough this would actually be an interesting worldbuilding question

Comment: A world building question might be "How to target an individual to make them sick or kill them? Would DNA be a viable option?" DNA might be used to make sure that the person targeted was the intended target but there are far easier ways to eliminate someone than using DNA targets.

Comment: Piece of advice when surfing the web : Never trust anyone online regarding your medical issues. Even if people answering you are real health experts and are not trying to scam you, they cannot diagnose effectively what you are suffering from.

Comment: So, this is an interesting scenario! What exactly is the worldbuilding problem you're trying to resolve?

Comment: @MarsToEarth - sorry, this is well outside the scope of what you've asked, but I re-read the post. The main, and only, reason I can think that someone would take hair from your pillow, is because it can be tested to see if you've taken drugs within the lifetime of the hair (roughly). The only real reason I can think to do that on the down low is if you're really worried about changes in someone's behavior. From one random internet stranger to another, I'd strongly recommend seeing a doctor. Particularly if the worries about the person in the post have increased over the last several months. I

Answer (score 3):

Will second the offtopic vote, but, also:

## No, you cannot use someone's DNA to target them

It's theoretically possible, I guess, but would be horrendously complicated. As Escaped dental patient says, you'd be looking at state actors, and not small ones - Russia/USA/China sized.

The rough idea would be:

1. find some unique sequence in the target's DNA, that doesn't occur in anyone else's
2. Design a payload sequence - this would be a toxin or similar, with proper promoter regions so your body would make it.
3. Design a Crispr system to target the unique sequence. When this finds the unique sequence identified in step 1, it will cleave the DNA at that point, and insert your payload strand
4. insert the whole system into an active virus, including the DNA code for the Crispr machinery. The payload should be set up so that the virus can replicate, but so that the payload doesn't become active until it is inserted into that unique sequence - maybe the ends are missing, and it needs to pick up a bit of sequence from the host DNA
5. release your virus into the wild! Most people will get it normally, your target will get it, produce the deadly toxin, and fall sick

The problem with all this, and, please, OP, read this far: None of this works yet. This is seriously, many, many years of research to develop these systems, from a dedicated germ warfare lab. It would be categorically illegal under pretty much every germ warfare treaty. And, this is pretty much the only way I can think of to target an individual (I work as a bio researcher)

This is not trivial stuff.

However, I'm sorry about your living situation. It sounds rough. However, some alternative hypothesises for the fevers. Be advised I'm not a doctor or other medical professional, but I think there are some simpler answers for why you keep getting sick:

1. being under a lot of stress, as it sounds like you are, tends to screw with your immune system.
2. Covid - it's still very much here. If you aren't vaccinated and can get it, do - it's a good thing to rule out.
3. Malnutrition - it sounds like you're in a super precarious situation, and refusing food. This is also going to screw your immune system up.

Generally, all this means that if you can, you should see a doctor. I'd also talk about the concerns you have that someone is adding things to your food, as it would be good to rule this out.

Comment: Well, it is debatable if it works or not. Who knows what the military is developing. The technology for targeted biowarfare has been around for decades (you don't need CRISPR for that). Still, I wouldn't bet on there being a usable weapon anywhere at the moment. But in any case, nobody would develop a weapon to target an individual, but rather a group (it would certainly be possible and in the interests of certain actors to develop a weapon ignoring caucasinas and targeting chineese, or vice versa). If you want to remove a person you can just shoot him/blow him up.

Comment: @Negdo targeted biowarfare _hasn't_ been around for decades, party because of _Homo sapiens_ habit of boldly going to strange new countries and enthusiastically sharing their genetic material, and partly because sophisticated modification of organisms is hella difficult, and partly because the modified stuff tends to mutate in distressing ways. We can't even target bacteria with custom viruses yet, and they're radically different to humans. Wake me when MDR-TB and MRSA are no longer a concern, then we'll talk targetted human bioweapons.

Comment: @StarfishPrime I didn't say targeted biowarfare exist (or has existed for decades). I said the TOOLS to build such weapons exist, and has for decades. Nor have I said it would be a good idea to build such weapons. But are you willing to bet that no genious from pentagon/chinese equivalent haven't ordered a biolab to work on that line of research? Also, since you can identify ethnical background from DNA sample (easily and cheaply!) it is definitively in the realm of possibilities that you could target those ethnical groups using same markers.

Comment: @Negdo the tools have been there in the same way that tools to build a fusion reactor have been around for decades, too.

Comment: @Negdo I'd argue the issues here are reliability - viruses lose  and gain bits of DNA all the time. And if they change the wrong bit, they could easily infect other people. I guess my standard here would be targeting to a person with the prescision of a DNA test, which I think we're arguably a very long way off managing